# Converting cURL POST request into AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, curl

I'm currently working on generating a post request for the LoyaltyLion API to create a custom loyalty reward for our Shopify store.

Since Shopify does not run on PHP, and for the sake of simplicity, I am curious to see how to convert the following cURL request into an AJAX POST request which we can include in the markup of our liquid file on the backend of Shopify.

Here's what I've got so far - I've tested this request locally and it works perfectly in cURL.

```
curl -X POST \
--user 'TOKEN:SECRET' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--url 'https://api.loyaltylion.com/v2/activities' \
--data '{
  "name": "winback_campaign",
  "customer_id": "CUSTOMER_ID",
  "customer_email": "CUSTOMER_EMAIL",
  "merchant_id": "REDACTED"
}'
```

If anyone would be able to point me in the right direction for this one or give me some helpful advice on how I can get this done in the future, that would be very helpful!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a website like https://curl.trillworks.com for finding the correct code.